# Mouse cursor became a big X

Tags: cursor, gtk2, gtk3, razor-qt

Below is a screenshot from Chromium browser, running in Razor-Qt desktop,

In other DEs, the cursor is just normal, but here you can see it becomes a big X, anyone know how to fix that? The cursor theme is not broken, as it works for KDE4 and XFCE4

[image]

P.S That happens to all GTK apps, Qt app works fine

Comment: Not that it helps much, but FYI: that's the original/default X cursor -- ie., the cursor you get on a minimal X install sans window manager or customized configuration.  So it is probably something *not* happening that leads to this.

Comment: Your DE is probably unable to read the GTK Icon set for some reason and hence is falling back to the default X icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the default cursor.  You can run:

```
 xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr
```

to set the pointer to the left arrow.  Typically, this goes in your .xinitrc file.

Comment: I am using Linux Mint 18.2 and an application changed the mouse cursor and didn't change it back when it closed. The above fixed the issue. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The cure for me lay in [cleaning up ~/.icons](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=823587#p823587), which for me somehow turned out to contain

```
$ cat ~/.icons/default/index.theme
# This file is written by LXAppearance. Do not edit.[Icon Theme]
Name=Default
Comment=Default Cursor Theme
Inherits=core
```

Wiping out ~/.icons/ brought back many cheery cursors - I never knew what I was missing. Helped for both Firefox and Chrome. (I use *icewm*.)